# C#: DataTable to Excel (Currency Formatting)

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, number-formatting, excel-interop

I've got a little problem and I don't know how to solve it.
The source for the DataTable is a MS SQL Server.
It takes the values from it via query.

That works everyting.
Excel expert works too.
But I've a problem with formatting the numbers.

In DataTabla everything is ok, because I've formatted the cells with:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Money"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C";
```

This works perfectly.
But when I export it to excel the numbers look like:

> 9700000

The origin number in the DataTable is:

> 970,00

So now I've to format the whole cells.
I do this with:

```
Range rg = excelSheet.Cells[3, 3];
rg.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "€ ##0.00";
```

This works. It takes all the cells and changes the format.
But the format isn't correct and I don't know how to specify the correct format.

Please help me out.
I need this as fast as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings,
Pukas.

Comment: What is new format which is not correct as per your findings?

Comment: In DataTable the format is correct and the numbers are shown as "970,00". But when I expert the DataTable to excel, the numbers look like "9700000" with much more zeros than the numbers contain, and with no commas. And this needs to be fixed.

Comment: Is the comma a decimal point?

Comment: Yes, the comma is a decimal point. Excel gets the wrong number-format and I don't know why. Because in the SQL-table it is correct and in DataTable it is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
Numbers were saved as "text" in the database and not as numbers.
I just changed the excel-format to "text" and now it works.